# A special cubic curve

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

How can I transfer following cubic curve to a  Weierstrass normal form?
$$2x^2y+4xy^2+2y^3-2axy-ay^2+a=0,$$
where $a$ is a fixed rational number.

Answer (score 3):

With difficulty, or [with Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=algcurves/Weierstrassform) (which has this built in). The algorithm is described in [this very nice (but nontrivial) paper by Mark van Hoeij.](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/c61b4b9f-7d38-402c-bf0d-1393497b1eb2/53d91c4671bc681f81b6ee677ce2d832)

Comment: How can I do by Maple?

Comment: @user119081 see the link.